# How to read XML SOAP data my client application send over the url?

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, soap

Basically I need to read the XML SOAP data which is sent by my client over URL.
I need to use java to read the XML SOAP data and insert the whole XML into data.

A client has given the sample XML format is as below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="WebService" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:StatusUpdate soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <Order xsi:type="xsd:string">?</Order>
      </web:StatusUpdate>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: your communication is happening over SOAP ..or REST(as you mentioned URL)

Comment: communication is happening over SOAP.

Comment: Anyone please suggest any solutions for the above?